# videos are resizing themselves while scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, react-native-video

I've been using the React Native Video package with FlashList, and I've encountered an issue where all the videos seem to squeeze and resize themselves or flicker when they first render while scrolling. After a few seconds, they render fine as expected. I've been facing this problem for a while. Has anyone else experienced this issue? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thanks!